# tex does not find my .sty files

Tags: texlive

I am using manjaro linux and I am having problem to set up correctly a latex project where I need to use my .sty files.

I've inserted those files in the directory:
`/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage`

But it is not correctly seen by my main.tex.

Why is not visible? Should't it be loaded automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On debian, you can add your own path to the TeX *environment variable*:

> export TEXINPUTS=.:~/mypath:

This is enough for the tex-engine to find your .sty files.

Remember that you must put it in your .bashrc or .profile or xsessionrc system files (usually **.profile** in order to be found by your tex editor). At least, you should restart your user desktop session.

I hope that works on manjaro.