Need help with env variables with tug-texlive
Due to a space problem (on my root partition) I removed my Ubuntu Texlive; and thought I'd try the direct install from tug.
But I am (I think) not getting the paths right.
In particular the manual pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex from the shell works.
But from inside emacs → org-mode → latexmk, I get:
Latexmk: Getting log file 'amar.log'
Latexmk: Bst file not found in search path:
  IEEEtran.bst
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex amar'
I couldn't open style file IEEEtran.bst
---line 164 of file amar.aux
 : \bibstyle{IEEEtran
 :                   }

Note to make latex work from emacs I need to put this in my emacs init
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/opt/texdirect/bin/x86_64-linux/"))
(push "/opt/texdirect/bin/x86_64-linux/" exec-path)

But maybe some more environment variable setups are needed?
Just for info:
/opt/texdirect:$ find . -iname IEEEtran.bst
./texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/ieeetran/IEEEtran.bst
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/confproc/example/papers/IEEEtran.bst
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/confproc/example/IEEEtran.bst


PS. If the most simple low tech answer is Just use your linux native texlive distribution! its ok. Please tell me!!

Added later
The key info that I did not put in the original question is that I had added to my .profile
if [ -d "/opt/texdirect/bin/x86_64-linux/" ] ; then
    PATH="/opt/texdirect/bin/x86_64-linux":$PATH
fi

This was not being found by emacs

you didn't accept the default /usr/local location it's seems, thats OK. and you just need to set your path, the fact that you need to do it again in emacs indicates it isn't set correctly in your environment. you seem to be using csh rather than (ba)sh so that prbably means it needs setting in .login or whatever it uses these days or if you set it in .cshrc make sure that you are launching emacs from a shell that has sourced that

if you are launching emacs from your desktop note you need to set the variable in the controlling shell for that which may not be using your user .cshrc

@DavidCarlisle Hehe! That seems to be it! If I start emacs from the shell (usual bash), it seems to work. Will check more and let you know. Tnx. [By default my emacs starts at login] [[Silly me]]

I thought it would be, you are approximately the 10000000000000000 person to fail at that step

oh sorry I only skimmed the setenv  in your question was elisp not csh, good:-)

@DavidCarlisle I couldnt have accepted the default location without hitting the problem I was trying to solve ­— a root partition too small to hold the texlive-full

probably duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547565/tex-does-not-find-my-sty-files/547569#547569

I'd rather delete the question @DavidCarlisle than have it as a duplicate to that one since that is about not finding my sty files while mine is about not finding system classes (by bibtex). My preferred is you make an answer and I'll accept it. But whichever you like

actually can you self answer as I don't actually have a desktop ubuntu and while I know the principle of setting it in the login shell, I might not get the relevant file names right. (I can live without the 15 pts:-) if you have a working version post that

As guided by David Carlisle's comments, its an emacs problem.
The emacs was starting as a daemon not from the shell.
As best as I can see (so far) if emacs is started from a shell, the org mode to pdf chain seems to work.
[Tnx David!]

I doubt very much emacs is starting as a daemon. /opt is usually for binary blobs. If you have a spare partition, mounting it at /usr/local/texlive would enable you to use the default paths and still get the installation off your root. If you don't have much in /usr/local, you could alternatively make that a mount point. (Or both, if you want to make life complicated.) That's not to say there's anything wrong with your solution - only that it isn't strictly true that you had to avoid the default paths in order to avoid the problem.

Did you solve the problem of starting from the desktop? If so, can you add what you needed to do to your answer? As it stands, this doesn't give people with the same problem the steps they need to follow to resolve it.

@cfr My (current) solution: (1) start a shell (2) start emacs (the way we did 25 years ago!) Ok its not ideal. But it sure beats spending another day or more struggling with another texlive install!

Not sure what you mean by I doubt emacs is a daemon See. (Note: I am not using exactly that; but a startup service in gnome)

I should have added: but nothing would surprise me about emacs ;). Still, I'm puzzled. What's --fg-daemon? I thought daemons were background? Now I'm thoroughly confused!

I don't know on Ubuntu, but you might look at /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/*. That's where I usually set environmental variables I want to be picked up system wide and in the GUI as well as shells. But, as I say, it might be somewhere else for Ubuntu.

@cfr There is an original --daemon switch that does that old fashioned double fork dance. Systemd prefers to handle the forking, waiting etc itself. So for the sake of systemd, emacs added a new fg-daemon (misnomer!!)

Misnomer indeed. ;)
